# Is it possible to create the selected row event though it has merge cell?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, onclick, highlight

I made a table for showing list of data. This table contains merging two rows which is I really need it to look that way. The tricky problem came when I try to highlight a single row.
It turns out that single TR is highlighted

[image: single TR is highlighted but the following TR is not]

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var preEl ;
var orgBColor;
var orgTColor;

function HighLightTR(el, backColor,textColor){
  if(typeof(preEl)!='undefined') {
     preEl.bgColor=orgBColor;
     try{ChangeTextColor(preEl,orgTColor);}catch(e){;}
  }
  orgBColor = el.bgColor;
  orgTColor = el.style.color;
  el.bgColor=backColor;


  try{ChangeTextColor(el,textColor);}catch(e){;}
  preEl = el;
}


function ChangeTextColor(a_obj,a_color){  ;
   for (i=0;i<a_obj.cells.length;i++)
    a_obj.cells(i).style.color=a_color;
}
```

html

```
<tr onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');" >
</tr>
```

How Can I highlighted the whole rows (the second column has two rows)
Thank your for your helps... ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The second row of the first and second columns is a different row object.  You'll need to change that row's color as well.

In other words, your `el` and `preEl` should be multi-row, instead of one row each.

Have you considered adding/removing classes to the rows and doing the color changes in CSS instead of in JavaScript?

Comment: Question: where do you get `el` from? I suppose `preEl` just stores the *previous* `el`, but where do you get `el`?  Which row?  You really have created *two* rows for each data item, only that in the last two columns the second row is hidden so you don't see it.  It doesn't mean that you have *one* row just because you see one in the last two columns.